# PDFClown .NET Open a Windows Explorer instead of specifying path

Tags: c#, visual-studio, pdfclown

Currently I have this test code

```
    File file = new File();
    Document document = file.Document;
    Page page = new Page(document);

    document.Pages.Add(page);

    PrimitiveComposer composer = new PrimitiveComposer(page);
    composer.SetFont(new StandardType1Font(document, StandardType1Font.FamilyEnum.Courier, true, false), 32);
    composer.ShowText("Hello World!", new PointF(32, 48));

    composer.Flush();
    file.Save("test.pdf", SerializationModeEnum.Incremental);
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("explorer", System.IO.Directory.GetParent(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName).ToString());
```

How can I open a general windows explorer save as prompt instead of saving to the hard code path "test.pdf"? (In `file.save()`)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `SaveFileDialog` for that:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sfezx97z(v=vs.110).aspx

```
   SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();  
   saveFileDialog1.Filter = "PDF File|*.pdf";  
   saveFileDialog1.Title = "Save PDF";  

   if(saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)  
   {  
       file.Save(saveFileDialog1.FileName, SerializationModeEnum.Incremental);
   }
```

Comment: This is really good but it opens two save as dialog boxes, one with no filename, then when i put one in it opens another with the full path in the name field, then i hit save and it saves in the right place; one dialog box would be better

Comment: @Jon0149 use the code I edited. The old one had two ShowDialog